# Addition/Multiplication table generator

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number, arithmetic

Given a number and either "+" or "*", return an addition or multiplication table with the dimensions of that number.

### Specifications

- The input will be formatted as `dimension, operation`.
- The program should not return anything if the operation input is not + or *.
- The program should not return anything if the dimension input is less than 1.

```
(4,*):
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 8 1216


(4,+):
1234
2456
3567
4678
```

The spaces between the numbers in the table should be equal to one less than the number of digits in `dimension^2` for multiplication, and for addition one less than the number of digits in `dimension * 2`.

Comment: A [couple](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67860/produce-an-xor-table) of quite [similar](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67183/a-multiplication-table-for-the-cheela) questions.  I'm not slamming my dup hammer just yet - I'll see what others have to say.

Comment: If the dimension is 10, how would one display the number 100 when there are only 2 digits in 99?

Comment: I suggest you allow a somewhat flexible output format. Having to conform to a very specific format is usually boring

Comment: Also input format checking is generally considered to be a tedious task that doesn't really add anything to a [tag:code-golf] challenge. *The program should not return anything if the operation input is not + or *. The program should not return anything if the dimension input is less than 1.*

Comment: Could you add an example of output for `(4,+)`?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. Please leave this question alone.

Comment: Mistakes are natural. The question is just on hold to give time for them to be cleared up, then it can be reopened. I find it useful to post my challenge ideas in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first to get feedback and spot any mistakes I made. I recommend it for future challenges.

Comment: Your example addition table is wrong. The top-left entry should be 2, for example.

Comment: I not see why limitate the number of operators in "•The program should not return anything if the operation input is not + or *." Until they are 2 arg to 1: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
Grid@Outer[If[#2=="+",Plus,Times],r=Range@#,r]&
```

Unnamed function taking two arguments, a number and one of the characters "+" or "*".

Sample output for the arguments `12`,`"*"`:

[image]

Comment: Does this actually meet the requirements? it looks like would output a multiplication table for any non `+` input, rather than only outputing a multiplication table on `*` and a addition table on `+`

Comment: @Taylor You are right! This answer seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + BSD Utils, 62 bytes

```bash
l=$[$1*$1-1]
eval echo \$[{1..$1}$2{1..$1}]|rs -g${#l} $[$1+1]
```

This calculates the number of spaces as per "number of digits in (dimension^2)-1", and not as shown in the example output, as currently written.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P8dWJVrFUEvFUNcwliu1LDFHITU5I18hRiW62lBPT8WwVsUIyoitKSpW0E1XqVbOqVUAadI2jP3//7@hwX8tAA)

This answer is very similar to [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67902/11259).

Works out-of-the-box on macOS.  `rs` may need to be installed on Linux systems:

```bash
sudo apt-get install rs
```

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 74 bytes

Worksheet funtion that takes input of `dimension, operation` from `A1, B1` and output a square array starting at the calling cell. Error handling accounts for a large portion of this response, and it is likely that large optimizations may be made to it.

```vb
=IfError(Let(r,Sequence(A1),c,Transpose(r),Ifs(B1="*",r*c,B1="+",r+c)),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

```
FN>¹L².VvyDg¹ngs-ú}J,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/mZ3dop8@hTXphZZUu6Yd25qUX6x7eVeulU/v/v6EhlxYA)

Also works with `-`, `^`, `m` and many more. See [here](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/Info.txt) for a list of commands this could work with by searching for "pop a,b".

Output (4,+):

```
 2 3 4 5
 3 4 5 6
 4 5 6 7
 5 6 7 8
```

Output (4,*):

```
 1 2 3 4
 2 4 6 8
 3 6 912
 4 81216
```

Output (4,^) [XOR]:

```
 0 3 2 5
 3 0 1 6
 2 1 0 7
 5 6 7 0
```

Output (4,c) [nCr]:

```
 1 2 3 4
 0 1 3 6
 0 0 1 4
 0 0 0 1
```

Output (4,Q) [a == b]:

```
 1 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: This breaks rule 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
{(⍳∘.⍺⍺⍳)⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/41HbhGqNR72bH3XM0HvUuwuMNms@6t1a@/9R31SgrHaGggkXhKmuCwbqUK4WTpnD00FS/wE)

## APL NARS, 22 bytes, 11 chars

```apl
{(⍳∘.⍺⍺⍳)⍵}
```

test:

```apl
  h←{(⍳∘.⍺⍺⍳)⍵}
  ×h 4
1 2  3  4
2 4  6  8
3 6  9 12
4 8 12 16
  +h 4
2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
  *h 7
1  1   1    1     1      1      1
2  4   8   16    32     64    128
3  9  27   81   243    729   2187
4 16  64  256  1024   4096  16384
5 25 125  625  3125  15625  78125
6 36 216 1296  7776  46656 279936
7 49 343 2401 16807 117649 823543
```

even if {(⍳∘.⍺⍺⍳)⍵} seems to be ok, {(⍳∘.⍵⍵⍳)⍺} it seems not ok

```apl
  f←{(⍳∘.⍵⍵⍳)⍺}
  4 f×
SYNTAX ERROR
```

Possible spaces are not as the examples in the question too...

h with g h n is the operator generator of table nxn For each diadic function g. In particular =h n is unit matrix for nxn.

Comment: Can you add a TIO (or equivalent). The output in your tests is incorrect but, without being able to test it, I don't know if it's due to an error in your solution or human error in pasting the wrong data into the solution.

Comment: @Shaggy the table + start from 0, where the table x start from 1 (in the examples of question)... Here start all from 1

Comment: In that case, your solution is invalid as it's not outputting what the challenge specifies it should.

Comment: The output for exponents `*h 7` shouldn't be included. It doesn't include the exponent values as the top row like it should.

Comment: @mbomb007 *h 7 first row 1^1 .. 1^7 2th row 2^1..2^7 3th row 3^1 3^2..3^7 where is the problem?

Comment: @RosLuP I took it as each function should have the values of `n` across each axis. I guess that's not required.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 111 bytes

```
{s=$2=="*"?2:$2=="+"?1:0;for(i=s-2;s&&++i<=$1;print"")for(j=s-2;++j<=$1;)printf("%"(s==1?2:$1)"s",s>1?i*j:i+j)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCsMgEEDRfY4xpEEdA1VCFtqpu96jm8BYiCET6KL06rXE3YcH//l@1foR6j0RGEg@tEJILlzjUnbFJKOPMgyIfKPexW3n9QDQJ@aGiLmJbrQouIASInfenAYBK3eX2OTAmPW31sliN1nTzRZ/ZTu4rFLHh/0D)

Output formatting may be slightly different than requested.

```
Input:
4,+
4,*
6,+

Output:
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

1   2   3   4
2   4   6   8
3   6   9  12
4   8  12  16

0 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 910
5 6 7 8 91011
6 7 8 9101112
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 123 bytes

```c
-Dp(i,c)for(i==0;i++<n;c)
-Df(c)if(x===*#c)p(i,puts(""))p(j,printf("%d ",i c j));
n;x;main(i,j){scanf("%d%c",&n,&x);f(+)f(*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEEWvEiItM0kKunCVZudFwsiUCRpDU6EgXt0YXX7ee3yaFqLWst/9PUoGcQlflWJm0MN1IO3G7MYdPYNFBoPv1k5n8yG@xaW26VJ6QsiPFSSEoxdr5@wJO2EgFIY9hGAOhD@xPLcKWmMfyZVV8va/UdqJIpUQ/Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 22 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

+17 bytes for the input validation and output formatting! :o

```
õ ïV ú f@©"*+"øVÃòU mq
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=9SDvViD6IGZAqSIqKyL4VsPyVSBtcQ&input=NAoiKiI)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 137 bytes

```
f=(n,s,b="")=>{for(i=0;i++<n;b+="\n")for(j=0;j++<n;b+=(r=s=='*'?i*j:s=='+'?i+j:"")+" ".repeat((n**2+"a").length-(r+"").length));return b}
```

Creates function `f` that returns the string. This calculates the number of spaces as per `number of digits in (dimension^2)-1`, and not as shown in the example output, as currently written. Outputs nothing if there is something other than `+` or `*`. I'm open to golfing tips.

#### Explanation

```
f=(n,s,b="")=>{
  for(i=0;i++<n;b+="\n")
    for(j=0;j++<n;b+=(r=s=='*'?i*j:s=='+'?i+j:"")+" ".repeat((n**2+"a").length-(r+"").length));
  return b
}
```

*I like when most of my code is just in my for-loops :)*

`n` is the number; `s` is the operator; `b` is the string that contains the output; `r` contains the actual value of the table cells

This is a system of two nested for-loops, I add `b` by `i*j` or `i+j` depending on the operator `(r=s=='*'?i*j:s=='+'?i+j:"")`, and then add the spaces afterward `" ".repeat((n**2+"a").length-(r+"").length)`.

At the end of the `j`-for-loop, I concatenate a newline to `b`.

#### Snack Snippet

```js
f=(n,s,b="")=>{for(i=0;i++<n;b+="\n")for(j=0;j++<n;b+=(r=s=='*'?i*j:s=='+'?i+j:"")+" ".repeat((n**2+"a").length-(r+"").length));return b}

console.log(f(10,'+'));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 - <s>154</s> 133 <s>127</s> bytes

```py
def s(d,o):R,s=range(1,d+1),' '*len(str((d,2)[o=='+']*d-1));return''.join([str((i*j,i+j)[o=='+'])+s+'\n'*(i==d)for j in R for i in R])
```

**Edit** : Changed spacing between number according to the new changes in the question.

```
Input :
8 +
Output :
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  
4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  
5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  
6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  
7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  
8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  
9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 160 bytes

```
(n,s,w=`${s==`*`?n*n:n+n}`.length)=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>((s==`*`?++j*i+j:s==`+`?i+j+2-!(i&&j):``)+` `.repeat(w)).slice(0,w)).join``).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Takes care to space the grid properly for both `+` and `-` versions, and ensures the first row and column are the dimensions and not the sum.

Comment: You might want to replace \n with an actual new line character, considering js thinks it ok to have a backtick string span multiple lines, that saves another character

Comment: @Luke_ As my description states, the byte count already takes that into account.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
function(n,o)write(format(outer(1:n,1:n,o)),1,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTydfs7wosyRVIy2/KDexRCO/tCS1SMPQKk8HhPM1NXUMdfI0/6dpGBrpKGkpaXJBWNpKmv8B)

Same I/O as the accepted answer.

Comment: This breaks rule 2.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
ɾ?\vdpĖ:vvS$fGL↲Ṡ⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvj9cXHZkcMSWOnZ2UyRmR0zihrLhuaDigYsiLCIiLCI0XG4qIl0=)

Without strict IO formats, the whole `:vvS$fGL↲Ṡ⁋` could be omitted

Answer (score -1):

### Python 3 - 140 bytes

```
a=lambda d,o:print(*map(lambda f:(' '*~-len(str([d,2][o>'*']*d))).join([str([i*f,i+f][o>'*'])for i in range(1,d+1)]),range(1,d+1)),sep='\n')
```

Comment: This breaks rule 2.

Answer (score -1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
(n,_)=>[...'.'.repeat(n)].map((a,i)=>Array.from({length:n},(v,k)=>_='*'?(k+1)*(i+1):k+i+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpRCsIwEESP000bFwS/ClE8h0hZalJj0k1IQ0HEs8eVgRl4b1600zYXn@uB08M2ZxqwnpQ53xCxkxSbLVVgdceVMgBpL/ZaCr3RlbTCJ1pe6nPkr4ZdB5GT6fruAmE4qh689BiG/6g2J95StBjTAg5OWn5Cfw)

Comment: This breaks rule 2.

Comment: It needs to be a string an not an array