# A Programming Puzzle of Mode Golf

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, hello-world, self-referential

Your task is to print the text `Good morning, Green orb!`, with every character repeated in place as many times as the most frequent byte in your source (the mode).  A trailing newline is permitted and need not be repeated.

For example if your source was

```
print p
```

Since `p` appears twice and every other byte appears once you would need to print

```
GGoooodd  mmoorrnniinngg,,  GGrreeeenn  oorrbb!!
```

Answers will be scored by the product of their byte count and the number of times the output is repeated.  For example the above code (if it worked) would score **7*2 = 14**.  The goal should be to minimize one's score.

Your code must contain at least 1 byte.

[Use this program to verify that your code and output match](https://tio.run/##LY5BasMwEEWvMgpZWGCXZp0okEXQAbosWci1ogzxzJixUmzI3VWlZPHh8d/m3cJ8j@NYkCbRDF/rnCN9nPkXVZgi53KF4Brnmo0XGYBEGTm14DVGBtHebI5Hp3Ea8Sfk2FBYkB70PdftnsuhC@3q3HJ5rhUv1tpCAdkNAkHTfOhSzKcK@0mR8/bavF5jPu0bdraUfwVT8bWgNgwARCKqzIjMKbUtgPdag2oSA7xc3xvzBw)

Comment: Functions are allowed, right?

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes, so long as they don't take input.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged [tag:quine]?

Comment: Morning can't be capitalized, can it haha?

Comment: @magicoctopusurn Nope the text should be the same.

Comment: [Sad face, was going to tie Jelly :P.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//@KAneKAmsK/4oCiwrQsy4bCqCBPcmIh//8 "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 19):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>384 * 106</s> 366 * 100 = 36,600

```
(((((((()()()))))))(()({}{}{}(([(({}{})){}()]((((({}())){})){}{}()(({})<([{}](((({}()())))([{}]([{}]()((()()())(()()({}()([(({})){}()](((((({}))))({}({}{}{}){})(({}){}()))))<((((([]){}){}){}<>)<>)>[])))))))(((((()()())()){}{}){}){})<>(((({})<>)))>{}{})))))<(<>({})<>)>))(<>((({}))()){}{}<>)<>(((({}<>()))))({}{}{}<>)<>{((<>{}<><({}<>)>)<{({}[()]<(({}))>)}{}>)<>}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9BDsIwDPtOfOAHVSXeUe0wuICQOHCt@vZiO90gXdckduLk9tmf78d@f80Zy6CTpqAPnYgWdgEG2MyUp1hXvjIo0frYDtidMuMfToF8zXHr/8YOYTTlJeJsSoIqsrYhsT5KBb/KzDH6b5fIARe31KVAPlBzKbckkmkCYZqgVW2BrOSLNd@J9GCF/GICW5ROr3Glkn0qyBV1iDjnvFy/)

### Explanation

The first thing I do is push the string

```
!bro neerG ,gninrom dooG
```

to the stack using pretty standard brain-flak Kolmogorov-complexity tactics.

```
(((((((()()()))))))(()({}{}{}(([(({}{})){}()]((((({}())){})){}{}()(({})<([{}](((({}()())))([{}]([{}]()((()()())(()()({}()([(({})){}()](((((({}))))({}({}{}{}){})(({}){}()))))<((((([]){}){}){}<>)<>)>[])))))))(((((()()())()){}{}){}){})<>(((({})<>)))>{}{})))))<(<>({})<>)>))(<>((({}))()){}{}<>)<>({}<>())
```

Then we push a counter to the off stack to tell us how many times to duplicate each character.  However I wasn't going to be able to determine what this counter was until I was done writing the program.

Next up we simultaneously reverse the string and duplicate each character in place the correct number of times.  Specifically the counter + 1.

```
{((<>{}<><({}<>)>)<{({}[()]<(({}))>)}{}>)<>}<>{}
```

These two parts of the program have a mode of 99 open parentheses.  However since we are most certainly going to need at least 1 parenthesis.  Here is where I noticed that the last character we pushed `!` conveniently has character code 33 which means we can use it to create 99, the exact number we want using only one additional parenthesis.  This is quite the coincidence but it works.

Comment: Ah yes, just pretty standard brain-flak Kolmogorov-complexity tactics. Those are the thing.

Comment: You, my good fellow, must be mad to even try this. I'm just going to +1 and walk away before my brain explodes from trying to understand all the brackets.

Answer (score 17):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes * 1 = 13

```
“¢Ȧ@XĊ'WÑṭḂ#»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4oCcwqLIpkBYxIonV8OR4bmt4biCI8K7//8)

Comment: Finally someone manages the elusive *1 answer. I had a feeling Jelly would be the language to do it...

Comment: @ETHproductions Haha, just halved my code while keeping  * 1

Comment: Haha dang I just found that right after you edited it

Comment: Out of curiousity, what exactly is the difference? How is the new compressed string half the length of the old one?

Comment: @ETHproductions I basically used  a non-optimal compressed string at first, then I used the [optimised Jelly compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145327/59487) which found the matches in the dictionary.

Answer (score 15):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes × 3 = 111

*-20 thanks to H.PWiz. -25 thanks to nimi.*

```hs
"Good m\111rning, Green orb!"<*[2..4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzX8k9Pz9FITfG0NCwKC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVHJRivaSE/PJPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkULx/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Haskell's operators FTW.

<sub>Self-reminder to never golf on mobile. I keep making dumb mistakes. I can push at least half the blame on mobile. :P</sub>

Comment: [Using `<*` to save bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvzX8k9Pz9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVHJRivaUE/PJPZ/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkULx/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA) (Note that I haven't checked its validity)

Comment: ...Bloody hell, Haskell almost has too many operators. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 235 x 77 = 18,095 points

Edit: -2 bytes thanks to @Dennis

```
-[>--<-------]>-[>+++++>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>+>+++>+++++>-->+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++++>+>+>+>+++[<]>-]>>----------->+++++>++>->+>-------->-------->+++++>>->++++++>------>+>---->+>+++++>++>>->--------->++>++>>-[>+<---]>--------<<[>>[-<+<.>>]<<,<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU9JCoBADHvQWF8Q8pHSgwqCCB4E3z/WWZzR9JK2SZf5nLZjvZY9RlGKQDKMnoYHLNFzJp4qIgzf@JoUPspIaagSNzO8Df7aLKQqirRtSJJ@aC752cgPFABKqiBgJA0YYDHe)

[TIO test](https://tio.run/##zZTNboQgEMdfBTc9aJRN91yYpIfGB@jRcGAra0kFDNJGk313y6rb3e15Dv4mJH@GYfia8Cn7L9W2kzad84G8j31QZv9mf7R31igbphORPOU83ZXO1cQ4b7VtClJ6pSxx/pjsALhXXas/ZFCpkYM236bqYzucB0ZlMXI@iPMYpciybDJSW147In3TM9qo8BrFS@e1DU@n9OJNkudsFYdsmmgFlDK6ICB28wuw2r2GWc8eSiF/tMdJFYupBAC9cQ2JkyH/G4B/w7CKa8QaelthDrlPurjittlygBXGKoCKspztAQRjBRNTiYnbLDUmBBODCeqdeUwsJhoT1J01mBSYoBYt6q@BWmdqs6DWGeprbvfXOGKSYPIL)

Wait, this *isn’t* code bowling?? \s

With only 8 usable characters, brainfuck is one of the worst languages to do this question. I had to start with minimising which character would inevitably appear the most, typically either `+` or `-`. After writing the first iteration of the code, I found it horribly unbalanced in favour of `+`s. I rearranged parts of the code, such as generation of larger numbers, to use more `-`. Finally, I ended up at <s>an *equal* amount of the two characters at 77</s> one less `-` than `+`. It’s certainly possible to reduce this further, which I’ll have a go at tomorrow.

But hey, at least I beat the [Brainflak answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152042/76162)

Comment: Hey, congratulations! I can't believe that it's even possible to do this in BF... Pretty if it can be done in the `;#` language ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 10):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 49 bytes * 2 = 98 <s>144</s>

```
/:G!4o3r8"1=5',0Grey9Z<@
\"b0=dnm 2'i%g<7R6~e.;o/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fyl3RJN@4yELJ0NZUXcfAvSi10jLKxoErRinJwDYlL1fBSD1TNd3GPMisLlXPOl///38A)

#### Explanation

```
/...@
\.../
```

This is the usual framework for linear programs that operate entirely in Ordinal mode. Unfolding the zigzag control flow, we get:

```
"G04d3m821i5g,7G6ee9;<:b!=onr "'=%'<0Rr~y.Zo@
```

The basic idea is to avoid characters which repeat more than twice with the help of a transliteration. The transliteration we're going to do is the following:

```
input: "G04d3m821i5g,7G6ee9;<:b!"
from:  "0123456789:;<"
to:    "onr "
```

The way transliteration works in Alice is that the `from` and `to` strings are first repeated to the LCM of their lengths, although in this case, all the matters is the length of the `from` string, so we get:

```
from:  "0123456789:;<"
to:    "onr onr onr o"
```

This way, we get four different characters to represent the `o`s, and three each for `n`, `r` and the space. We can generate the `from` string using range expansion as follows:

```
'<   Push "<".
0    Append a zero.
R    Reverse.
r    Range expansion.
```

The only issue now is that we'd need four `"` for both the `input` and the `to` string. To avoid that, we put them both into a single string and split it at a `=` used as a separator.

```
"G04d3m821i5g,7G6ee9;<:b!=onr "
     Push the string containing both parts.
'=%  Split around "=".
```

The rest is just:

```
~   Swap "from" and "to".
y   Transliterate.
.Z  Duplicate and interleave. This duplicates each character.
o   Print.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s><sup>74×6=</sup>444</s><sup><sup><sup><sub>[crossed out 444 is still regular 444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103403/print-the-f-%c3%97-f-times-table/146450?s=29|0.0000#146450)</sub></sup></sup></sup> <s><sup>77×5=</sup>385</s> 81×4=324

```c
f(q){char*a="Go\157d morning, G\162een o\162b!";for(q=0;q<96;)putchar(a[q++/4]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No1CzOjkjsUgr0VbJPT/G0NQ8RSE3vygvMy9dR8E9xtDMKDU1TyEfxEhSVLJOyy/SKLQ1sC60sTSz1iwoLQHp1UiMLtTW1jeJ1bSu/Z@bmJmnoVmdpgHiAAA)

Comment: o0 wat did you do to your post header

Comment: had a bit of fun

Comment: where did the crossed out 44 meta post go?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 × 3 = 186

```python
lambda:`sum(zip(*['Good morning, Green \x6frb!']*3),())`[2::5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfUJSZV6Kg8T8nMTcpJdEqobg0V6Mqs0BDK1rdPT8/RSE3vygvMy9dR8G9KDU1TyGmwiytKElRPVbLWFNHQ1MzIdrIyso09r@mgobmfwA)

Answer (score 6):

## Vim, <s>42</s> 41 keystrokes × 3 = 123

```
iGod morning, Green orb!<Esc>2|qsyl2pl@sqX0@s
```

Explanation:

1. `iGod morning, Green orb!<Esc>`
   Write the string `God morning, Green orb!` (one `o` missing).
2. `2|`
   Jump to the first `o`.
3. `qsyl2pl@sq`
   Create a recursive macro `s`.
   As a side effect, triple the current `o`.
4. `X0`
   Remove one `o` and jump to the beginning.
5. `@s`
   Run the macro `s`, which repeat each character twice.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 46 bytes × 2 = 92

(Contains unprintables)

```apl
2/⎕UCS(¯18+⍳24)+⎕UCS'X~r-yz|wqum1$Jtfemln]'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4z0gXSoc7DGofWGFtqPejcbmWhqQ4TUI@rrinQrq2rKC0tzDVW8StJSc@Vy8mKl1f//BwA)

+Alot of bytes thanks to Dyalog's code page, thanks to @Adám for pointing that out.

Comment: [84](http://tryapl.org/?a=2/%u2395ucs%28%u237324%29+%u2395UCS%27Fml%60%1Bghje_c%5B%1F%128bTS%5B%0CZ%5CK%09%27&run)

Comment: That's really genius, @Adám

Comment: I'm afraid you have to settle for [92](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4z0gXSoc7DGofWGFtqPejcbmWhqQ4TUI@rrinQrq2rKC0tzDVW8StJSc@Vy8mKl1f//BwA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online") since `~⎕AV∊⍨⎕UCS 18`.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 68 × 3 = 204

```
0000000: 6a 3b 6d 61 69 6e 28 29 7b 77 68 69 6c 65 28 6a  j;main(){while(j
0000010: 3c 37 32 29 70 75 74 63 68 61 72 28 7e 22 b8 90  <72)putchar(~"..
0000020: 90 9b df 92 90 8d 91 96 91 98 d3 df b8 8d 9a 9a  ................
0000030: 91 df 5c 32 32 30 8d 9d de 22 5b 6a 2b 2b 2f 33  ..\220..."[j++/3
0000040: 5d 29 3b 7d                                      ]);}
```

*Thanks to @MDXF for saving 9 points and paving the way for 6 more!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHPbsIwDMbP5Ck@ceCPEKFNaNIMxItsO7RJS0FAWQGBxNird3HKAe00y0qsz/ZPdpJnp6q93RymDZZLDPkQK@xrV6zrXcltG3X2BpVB5lAOKoYyUAVECmGgc2gNlQbRQiWk@2JsF/tscxiN79dqsytGWxZAsUdJC6khRWiPoBPoOZQMkBhaEEF7vkCewkTAUovx8XK2VdaMfvqcdyjhUT5rcrgSRlCcOpgYRoUzhZOU8hDSM3LwP9ahJKFiKk4sDUbe0RxcmCTJaSmRBy8hJaE@hIg8o/@@nUxmskPNPSpxtJp/Lu3wL/scLx4tZ@zOeleLqX35AdYrbFWzXvij4@klg2@U9c6rwkenujn763LYfFH/U5g2h2f/A6uBYGxtX9kYDMBnGa8v5/YX)

#### Alternate version, printable ASCII, 69 × 3 = 207

```c
j;main(k){while(j<72)putchar("Gnmg$hiuf`dl -I}ut|3{gt6"[k=j++/3]^k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOjcxM08jW7O6PCMzJ1Ujy8bcSLOgtCQ5I7FIQ8k9LzddJSOzNC0hJUdB17O2tKTGuDq9xEwpOts2S1tb3zg2LlvTuvb/fwA)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70972/discussion-between-dennis-and-md-xf).

Answer (score 4):

## C, 78 × 4 = 312

```
*s=L" ÞÞÈ@ÚÞäÜÒÜÎX@äÊÊÜ@ÞäÄB";main(y){while(*++s)for(;y++%5;putchar(*s/2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2NZHSeFQ3@F5QNjhcHgWkFpyeM7hSUDcF@EAlFhyuAsI5ziAJVqclKxzEzPzNCo1q8szMnNSNbS0tYs10/KLNKwrtbVVTa0LSkuSMxKLNLSK9Y00Na1r//8HAA)

### <s>356</s> <s>332</s>

Comment: Commenting because I'm tired of finding it in my browser history every time I want to golf: I used [this](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIbveYrfSOhsNsG2CIJrIHj2AQSbQ9lk2wXdliRFQunNg3jowaMUT30S98HSsREZhhnm/2fm0@lC675/mVtHYhsA1rXQCWwCvdq49mkyvSmQYTveKVZfl/a5ApHm0aJq9XJekxC4yJBOBOv429KFlL9@s6pBls1jBYs78DVupBy81oAGvy2GCbCumcBQOIr0CBSV4nbWRuXMhWemfyxeUMGu7y/LylhXwQxoFEvZCP5KXXatujRV681AGTdXUyGCLomb7CHEz95/c7zn/ovL0R/8J@f@MWfh6D84DvlZeLsP1Qk) to find the number of character repetitions.

Comment: And [this](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/79OT4NLQddSwcGaS6FOQY9LU@3/f/f8/BSF3PyivMy8dB0F96LU1DyF/KIkRQA) to encode the string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes * 2 = 48

```
`Good ¶rÍÁ,
GÎ9 b!`m²·¸
```

Contains an unprintable. [Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YEdvb2QgtnLNwSwKR845II5iIWBtsre4&input=)

The majority of the program is just a compressed string, which decompresses to

```
Good morning,
Green orb!
```

and `m²` then `m`aps each character by repeating it `²`wice <sup>okay, that was a bit of a stretch</sup>. Space is the only character that appears 3 times in the compressed string; to save one instance we replace it with a newline, then use `·¸` to split on newlines and immediately join on spaces. While 2 bytes longer, it substantially reduces the score (from 66 to 48).

Now if only there were a short way to do it using no character twice...

Comment: Because I can't see it: which character is in the source three times? I see several things that have a count of 2, but not 3.

Comment: @Draco18s None, the score is 24*2.

Comment: Then the output is wrong. You're printing each character 3 times instead of twice.

Comment: @Draco18s Dangit, posted the wrong link... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `*salute*` And now that I look at your answer I see it has ² whereas the link had ³ :)

Comment: @Draco18s Yep, and they do the same thing, but `²` twice and `³` thrice :-)

Comment: Yup, I know exactly what it does, just that I was looking at the source *in the link* as compared to the source *in the answer.* Otherwise I'd have seen that it was a bunged link. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65 bytes * 5 = 325</s> <s>59 bytes * 5 = 295</s> 62 bytes * 4 = 248

```r
cat(gsub('(.)',strrep('\\1',4),"Good Mo\x72ning, Green orb!"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xCsIwFEV3v@JZhySQCkpF/6A4uDlmSduXttAm8vIq/fsYOjgp3Dtd7jmUUmtZ9nFppJBHJXRkInxJYcxJ6Erpog6hg0cw6/XsR99rqAnRQ6BmXyi13YXxQu1mu0q2zYRyYXd7hrtnWfylb/yL0uYr@GUwWZGj4ABz6BDKEnhAQrC5FQQHEd9IdoJudC4PnqEdLNmWkWL6AA)

There are 4 `(or,')` characters.

Comment: I've never seen `strrep` before, that should come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 97 bytes * 10 = 970

```
	S ='Good Morning, Green orb!'
y	S	LEN(1) . y rem . s	:f(p)
	x	=x DUPL(y,10)	:(y)
p	OUTPUT	=x
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcm7CoAgFADQ@foVtymFiIKmoC1p6QXlD0QWQXlDF/16azrDcYY2uqsYYcEm7Yh2HMiay5wZdlZrg2S3JGUBFujlyEuBOQa0@vl1UB/8FQw8NB5bNfc8ZGUhoOZBsBcmtc5q/Y/JsY3xAw)

yeah........SNOBOL requires operators to be separated by whitespace, and there are whitespace requirements that are quite awkward. There are 9 `'\t'` and 10 `' '` in the code, so any improvements will require a fairly significant change in approach.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 52 bytes × 3 = 156

```ruby
puts"Good morning, Green \x6frb!".gsub(/(.)/,'\1'*3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFjJPT8/RSE3vygvMy9dR8G9KDU1TyGmwiytKElRSS@9uDRJQ19DT1NfRz3GUF3LWPP/fwA)

Comment: Nice way to avoid repeating characters

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 × 2 = 118 points

```
$_="GSSdYmoVRing,YGVIen orb!";y<H-Z>[d-t ],s<.>[$&x2]eg;say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbJPTg4JTI3PywoMy9dJ9I9zDM1TyG/KElRybrSxkM3yi46RbdEIVan2EbPLlpFrcIoNjXdujix8v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 × 3 = 153 <del>156</del> points

```
s""GOOd morning, Green orb!";y'O'o';s/./$&x3/eg;say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YScnd3z9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVHJulLdXz1f3bpYX09fRa3CWD813bo4sfL//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 43 × 4 = 172 points

```
say"Good morning, Green orb!"=~s/./$&x4/egr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJPT8/RSE3vygvMy9dR8G9KDU1TyG/KElRybauWF9PX0WtwkQ/Nb3o//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Saved 2 bytes in each solution thanks to @Xcali (a few changes ago). For all optimizations look at the edits.

Comment: Making this a program instead of a function would save 2 bytes (4 points): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJ3d8/JTQ3P8gvMy9dJ9Q9KDU1TyE/xtDMKElRybau0sZHN8wuOke3RCG2yLau2EbPLlpFTUUtNr3o//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali, but your change needs a nonstandard option `-M5.010`, which also counts

Comment: That one is free: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/11939#11939

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62*4 = 248

*Thanks to @ovs and @Giuseppe!*

```
lambda:"".join(c*4for(c)in"G\x6f\x6fd mor\x6eing, Green orb!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNykl0UpJSS8rPzNPI1nLJC2/SCNZMzNPyT2mwiwNhFMUcvOLgIzUzLx0HQX3otTUPIX8oiRFJc3/BUWZeSUKaRqa/wE)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51*6 = 306

```
print"".join(c*6for c in"Good morning, Green orb!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESUkvKz8zTyNZyywtv0ghWSEzT8k9Pz9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVFJ8/9/AA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70*5 = 350

```
lambda:"".join(c*5for(c)in"Gxxd mxrning, Green xrb!".replace('x','o'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE5DoAgEADAryANYAyFiY2JNZ@w4VQMLGRjsb4eZ/r33g3WkY5zFFtdsDvn@mkZpJ@31FB6lYEbosAqIWS4FmYwRmCEbuIaYy/WRylILKIJpUbHDC9LUo0f)

*Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder for saving a byte from both versions!*

Comment: You can remove the space between `6` and `for`.

Comment: [57*4=228](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNykl0UpJSS8rPzNPI1nLJC2/SCNZMzNPyT2mwiwtRSE3vyjGLDUzL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVFJ839BUWZeiUKahuZ/AA)

Comment: @ovs that's not quite right, I think you need two `\x6f`s which is still good for 244

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 35 bytes * 2 = 70

```
IG²od morning, GreeN ORb!5h3~Óˆ/°°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39P90Kb8FIXc/KK8zLx0HQX3otRUPwX/oCRFadMM47rDkw916B/acGjD//8A)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 4947 b26f 6420 6d6f 726e 696e 672c 2047  IG.od morning, G
00000010: 7265 654e 204f 5262 211b 3568 337e d388  reeN ORb!.5h3~..
00000020: 2fb0 b0                                  /..
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md) * 1 = 16

```
7n]ēæ¬⁹≡qa╔αXE‘⁽
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=N24lNUQldTAxMTMlRTYlQUMldTIwNzkldTIyNjFxYSV1MjU1NCV1MDNCMVhFJXUyMDE4JXUyMDdE,v=0.12)

Compression!

Though, if `Green` wasn't capitalized like that, this could be 3 bytes shorter :/

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 77 bytes * 3 = 231

```
import StdEnv
f=[[b,b..]%(0,2)\\a<-:"Qyyn*wy|xsxq6*Q|oox*\171|l+",b<-[a-'
']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4wrzTY6OkknSU8vVlXDQMdIMyYm0UbXSimwsjJPq7yypqK4otBMK7AmP79CK8bQ3LAmR1tJJ8lGNzpRV51LPTb2f3BJItAwW4W0//@S03IS04v/6yb91/X0@e9SmZeYm5lcDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm/blob/master/code_page.md) * 1 = 20

```
”1Gäåa¬Î|òÙγy[õ↕~LzN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vaG0y///igJ0xR8Okw6VhwqzDjnzDssOZzrN5W8O14oaVfkx6Tv//)

Gotta love compression, although unfortunately it's not as good as SOGL's.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 32 bytes × 2 = 64

```
"Gnmg$hiuf`dl -I}ut|3orb!"K,.^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X8k9LzddJSOzNC0hJUdB17O2tKTGOL8oSVHJW0cvzir@/38A)

Pushes a string, then XORs the first 20 character with `[0, 1, …, 19]`, then duplicates each character.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>49*5</s> 58 bytes * 4 = 232 pts

<sup>-13 pts thanks to ASCII-only</sup>

```powershell
-join("Good m{0}rning, Green {0}rb!"-f'o'|% t*y|%{"$_"*4})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ8k9Pz9FIbfaoLYoLzMvXUfBvSg1NU8BxE9SVNJNU89Xr1FVKNGqrFGtVlKJV9IyqdX8/x8A)

Uses formatting to go from 5 `o`s to 4 to chip out some numbers

Comment: [232?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ8k9Pz9FIbfaoLYoLzMvXUfBvSg1NU8BxE9SVNJNU89Xr1FVKNGqrFGtVlKJV9IyqdX8/x8A)

Comment: [close](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ0PJPT8/RSG32qC2KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPAcRPUlTSTVPPV9fULUotyElMTlXS0NNU0tFQVzFU1zLR1Pz/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), Score: 22 (22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) * 1)

```
…‚¿•´,„ˆ¨èã).ªðý23£'!«
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX//@KApuKAmsK/4oCiwrQs4oCey4bCqMOow6MpLsKqw7DDvTIzwqMnIcKr//8)

**Explanation:**

NOTE 1: The *wrap stack into list* builtin `)` is used instead of the builtin *pair* `‚`, because the `‚` is already part of the dictionary word `good`.
NOTE 2: The two commas in the code `‚` and `,` may look the same, [but are different unicode characters](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPv//48aZukAAA). The first one is usually used for the builtin *pair*, and the second for the builtin *print to STDOUT with trailing newline*. In this case they are used for the dictionary word `good`, and the expected comma in the output however.

```python
…‚¿•´,        # 3-word dictionary string "good morning," (the comma counts as the third word)
„ˆ¨èã         # 2-word dictionary string "green orbit"
)             # Wrap everything on the stack into a list: ["good morning,","green orbit"]
 .ª           # Sentence capitalize all strings: ["Good morning,","Green orbit"]
   ðý         # Join by spaces: "Good morning, Green orbit"
     23£      # Only leave the first 23 characters: "Good morning, Green orb"
        '!«  '# Append a "!": "Good morning, Green orb!" (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `…‚¿•´,` is `"good morning,"` and `„ˆ¨èã` is `"green orbit"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 46 bytes * 4 = 184 points

```powershell
"Good morning, Green orb!"-replace'.',('$0'*4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8k9Pz9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVFJtyi1ICcxOVVdT11HQ13FQF3LRPP/fwA)

Comment: That's clever. I completely forgot about `$0`

Comment: :| wait i tried this but only after doing the format so it didn't work as well as this did

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ what about TIO link?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes, score 38

```
‛ƛ⁋`øø, ×ŀ ⋎Ė!`"Ṅ2•
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9B%C6%9B%E2%81%8B%60%C3%B8%C3%B8%2C%20%C3%97%C5%80%20%E2%8B%8E%C4%96!%60%22%E1%B9%842%E2%80%A2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
‛ƛ⁋                 # Compressed string
   `øø, ×ŀ ⋎Ė!`     # Compressed string
               "Ṅ   # Pair and join by spaces
                 2• # Double each character
```

Comment: Am I foolish, or is space thrice present?

Comment: @thejonymyster *slaps face* fixing

Comment: @thejonymyster Fixed.

Comment: nice 38 score :D

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes * 3 = 183

```
_=>'Good morning, Gr\145en \x6f\x72b!'.replace(/./g,"$&$&$&")
```

```js
f=
_=>'Good morning, Gr\145en \x6f\x72b!'.replace(/./g,"$&$&$&")
console.log(f())
```

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes * 4 = 204

```
_=>'Good morning, Green orb!'.replace(/./g,'$&$&$&$&')
```

Answer [suggested by @ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152016/a-programming-puzzle-of-mode-golf/152025#comment371516_152025).

```js
f=
_=>'Good morning, Green orb!'.replace(/./g,'$&$&$&$&')
console.log(f())
```

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes * 4 = 292

```
_=>`G00d mo1ning, G244n orb!`.replace(/./g,_=>(('o'+!0)[_]||_).repeat(4))
```

```js
f=
_=>`G00d mo1ning, G244n orb!`.replace(/./g,_=>(('o'+!0)[_]||_).repeat(4))
console.log(f())
```

## JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes * 6 = 348

```
_=>'Good morning, Green orb!'.replace(/./g,_=>_.repeat(6))
```

```js
f=
_=>'Good morning, Green orb!'.replace(/./g,_=>_.repeat(6))
console.log(f())
```

Comment: Alternatively, change `_=>_` to `'$&'`

Comment: Alternaternatively, I think you can just do `'$&$&$&$&$&$&'` for the replacement, which then I think allows you remove two instances and go down to having several characters tied at 4, drastically reducing the score...

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, didn't know about that replacement pattern!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes × 2 = 62 points

```
“2ðƈZ(Øṡdȷ¿Ɱ’ṃ“God mrnig,eb!”x2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxyjwxuOdURpHJ7xcOfClBPbD@1/tHHdo4aZD3c2AyXd81MUcovyMtN1UpMUHzXMrTD6//9/tKGOERAa65jomAJpMx1zHQsgttQxNAAKGQIFDA1ByBzIA0kbGukYGsc@3NFqaAwA)

**Explanation**

```
“2ðƈZ(Øṡdȷ¿Ɱ’ṃ“God mrnig,eb!”x2
“2ðƈZ(Øṡdȷ¿Ɱ’                     Base 250 number
              “God mrnig,eb!”     Unique characters of "Good morning..."
             ṃ                    Convert the base 250 number in base 13 then index into the string "God mr..."
                             x2   Repeat each character twice because “ occurs twice in the source (and now 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 36×4=144

```
Good morning, Green orb!
.
$&$&$&$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fyz0/P0UhN78oLzMvXUfBvSg1NU8hvyhJkUuPS0UNAv//BwA) There are three newlines and four `o`s, so there's nothing more to be done.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 36 * 2 = 72

```
`GXVWOP^4W_[afdc\hiB`N$29+L-''.
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z@B1T0ijCPcPyDOhE86PD46MS0lWTwmI9MpwU/FyFLbR1ddXe//fwA)**

The main principle of this answer is that each character `n` is stored as `n + index - 29` in order to avoid the repetition in the original string. This mapping created the string in the backticks. The rest of the program simply decodes this and prints each character twice:

```
` ... `              \ Push the encoded string
       N             \ Remove printing delimiter
        $            \ While there are items left on stack:
         29+         \   Add 29 to top of stack
            L-       \   Subtract current length from top of stack
              ''.    \   Print twice, then pop
```

Bytes used twice: `` `'W ``

**Changelog**

- Golfed length from 41 to 38, by changing decoding method.
- Golfed length from 38 to 37 by subtracting 29 from each encoded character to prevent multibyte characters.
- Golfed length from 37 to 36 by using implicit 'end loop'

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 55x4 = 220 points

```
"Good morning, Green orb!".split(//).each{|x|print x*4}
```

Im quite annoyed that using each_char makes the count of r's 5..

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 414 * 163 = 67,482

```
-[>-<---]>-------->>>-[>+>+>+>>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>>+>+>++<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<-----]<-[>+<-------]>-->+++++++++>+++++++++>-->------------------->+++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++++>++++++++>+++>++++++++>+>------->------------------->------------------------------->++++++++++++>->->++++++++>------------------->+++++++++>++++++++++++>---->>++++[<++++++++>-]<+[<]>[<<<[>+>+<<-]>>[->.<]>[-]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBBCsMwDHtQUF8g9JHgw1oojMEOhb4/c9KUeWsplQ@WhCMHj8vj@Z7X6VUKskAAJnRIcjO16m2vqLeWeL9aurGGs@@qWz2kIzC3cYSOgylAkQSxR51G4hq/C3xc4Y8X03/v2l0rzfyaRpemTLIdnPSDKENDdZ1bKR8)

I'm not very good at brainfuck so this is likely far from optimal, but it works.

### Explanation

The first part is

```
-[>+>+>+>>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>>>+>+>+>+>+>>+>+>++<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<+<-----]<-[>+<-------]>-->+++++++++>+++++++++>-->------------------->+++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++++>++++++++>+++>++++++++>+>------->------------------->------------------------------->++++++++++++>->->++++++++>------------------->+++++++++>++++++++++++>---->>++++[<++++++++>-]<+[<]>
```

This writes the charcodes for

```
Good morning, Green orb!
```

to memory in order.  It is certainly the place that could use the most optimization.

Then we have

```
[<<<[>+>+<<-]>>[->.<]>[-]>]
```

Which goes and prints off each character as many times as we tell it.  Since there are 163 pluses in the program we tell it to print each character 163 times.

```
-[>-<---]>--------
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s><sub>84*5=420</sub></s> 83 bytes * 5 = 415

```ml
map(fn$ =>map(fn _=>print(str$))[0,2,3,4,5])(explode"Good mor\110ing, Green orb!");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcY7CoAwDADQq0RxaCGC30l09RAqolhFaJMSO3j7Ovim9zibOxuYYnSbVydl0A//YO0HLzcF9QTJtJ4KrLDGBttFK/N6y4dJR@YDHMtclsVNF8IoxhCw7Emquxg/)

---

#### Alternative approach (same score)

```ml
String.map;it(fn c=>(print(it(fn _=>c)"vwxyz");c))"Good mor\110i\110g, Green orb!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/8/uKQoMy9dLzexwDqzRCMtTyHZ1k6jAChWogHhx9vaJWsqlZVXVFYpaVona2oquefnpyjk5hfFGBoaZIKIdB0F96LU1DyF/KIkRSXr//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 42 bytes * 4 = 168

```
"Good morning, Green orb!"~sL(si/4*Pi1+~i)
```

Outputs:

```
GGGGoooooooodddd    mmmmoooorrrrnnnniiiinnnngggg,,,,    GGGGrrrreeeeeeeennnn    oooorrrrbbbb!!!!
```

[Try it online!](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=Ikdvb2QgbW9ybmluZywgR3JlZW4gb3JiISJ-c0woc2kvNCpQaTErfmkp&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes * 2 = 44

```
”‚¿•´,ˆ¨ orb!”'m5ǝ2иζJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcPcRw2zDu1/1LDo0Bad022HVijkFyUpAoXVc02PzzW6sOPcNq///wE)

---

If I am able to output title-cased:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
”‚¿•´,ˆ¨ Orb!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//@KAneKAmsK/4oCiwrQsy4bCqCBPcmIh//8)

Please note, CP-1252 `‚` is not a comma, therefore there are no dupes.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 41 bytes x 7 = 287

```
|v"Good morning, Green orb!"
o\! !\:::|oo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v6ZMyT0/P0UhN78oLzMvXUfBvSg1NU8hvyhJUYkrP0ZRQTHGysqqJj///38A)

As 'o' is used as the print character, this uses some mirrors to reuse them for printing.

Comment: @HeebyJeebyMan completely forgot to add that on, changed it now thanks :)

Comment: [44*3](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X6nMPT9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSZGrWt8uRtEqPsaqTjHeptqqNqbu/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 3 * 54 bytes = 162

```perl6
<<"G{q`o`x 2}d"morning,'Green'orb!>>~~say S:g{.}=$/x 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKcn5KqYKtQGP3fxkbJvbowIT@hQsGoNkUpN78oLzMvXUfdvSg1NU89vyhJ0c6urq44sVIh2Cq9Wq/WVkW/QsH4f6w1F9gQPdcwRx9rLi6QAohAcn5ukp5TYrpebmKFhpZeWWJOaarmfwA)

I started off with the normal:

```perl6
"Good morning, Green orb!"~~(S:g{.}=$/x 4).say
```

Which simply replaces each letter by 4 copies of itself and prints. The mode characters were the spaces and the `o`s, so I changed the string part to a word quote with interpolation:

```perl6
<<Good morning,'Green'orb!>>~~say S:g{.}=$/x 4
```

This decreased the spaces down to 3. Next was the `o`, which I decided to double in the `oo` part of `Good`.

```perl6
<<"G{q`o`x 2}d"morning,'Green'orb!>>~~say S:g{.}=$/x 4
```

This involved wrapping the `Good` in interpolating quotes of its own, then having to use a custom `q`uoting construct to do the o character, since the quote characters were taken.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 57 bytes × 4 = 228

```
END{$0="Good morning, Green orb!";gsub(/./,"&&&&");print}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lWsXAVsk9Pz9FITe/KC8zL11Hwb0oNTVPIb8oSVHJOr24NElDX09fR0kNCJQ0rQuKMvNKav//BwA)

Comment: saved 2 bytes and 8 points [assuming empty input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/55918)

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 35 bytes * 4 = 140

**Solution:**

```
`0:,/4#'"Good morning, Green orb!";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P8HASkffRFldyT0/P0UhN78oLzMvXUfBvSg1NU8hvyhJUcn6/38A)

**Explanation:**

Nothing fancy here, the most common letter is `o` which occurs `4` times.

```
`0:,/4#'"Good morning, Green orb!"; / the solution
        "Good morning, Green orb!"  / the string to be displayed
     4#'                            / 4 take (#) each (') repeats each character 4 times
   ,/                               / flatten these lists
`0:                               ; / print to stdout (`0:) and swallow return value (;)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 53*3=159 bytes

```swift
{"Good morning, Green \u{6f}rb!".flatMap{[$0,$0,$0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@V9QlJlXoqHxv1rJPT8/RSE3vygvMy9dR8G9KDU1TyGmtNosrbYoSVFJLy0nscQ3saA6WsVAB4xia2v/a2poav4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, score: 455 (91 bytes * 5)

```java
x->{for(var s:"G\157od mo\162ning, G\162een orb!".split(""))System.out.print(s.repeat(5));}
```

The `e`, `o`, `r`, and `t` are all four used 5 times.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY6xCsIwEIb3PsXZKQEbUKiCRVcnXQQX63BNo6SmSUnSopQ@e021y/13Bz/fV2GHSVW@Rq7QOTih1H0EILUX9oFcwHk6ATojS@DkOkVHs/AbojCcRy85nEHDHsZ3cugfxpIOLbhdfMxX6daUUJt8tVlrqZ9LOE6rEBqMLRYxc42SnsQxpZeP86JmpvWssQFPHLOiEehJSmk2jNmEa9pCBdxM/TnVwZhcfKg8b3dA@tfVjBPdKjWbDuMX)

**Explanation:**

```java
x->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(var s:"G\157od mo\162ning, G\162een orb!"
                         //  Push String "Good morning, Green orb!"
            .split(""))  //  And loop over its characters as Strings
    System.out.print(s   //   Print the current character
      .repeat(5));}      //   Repeated 5 times
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 42*4 = 168

```
a:"Good morning, Green orb!"Fi,#a{L4O(ai)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0UrJPT8/RSE3vygvMy9dR8G9KDU1TyG/KElRyS1TRzmx2sfEXyMxU7P2/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 59 × 3 = 177

```julia
map(y->print(y^3),["Good morning, G\x72ee\x6E \x6Frb!"...])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xa8MwEIV3/wpV06k4AqfQQsBZkjZTl65JCtf4kihIsiPpWvvXO3Kg3bocvPf4Pu7C1mDVj7EO@COlHB12MMyWXTA@wfD5pMqt3LRtI1wbvPGnUmx2/cucaNc/v4p83sLXg9Ra79WY@W21IN/Mqn1xN1gPURUsasHeXJmm1OS0NocEqzMGDayErpfi0LJPGkykK6Od6lJ80DEDShV/Moe9cezgGy1ThGYa/98eLflTOk@OgnIN75RQdxgi3btfMv9kYmdxyNB4Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 60x4 = 240

```
=CONCAT(REPT(MID("Good morning, Green orb!",ROW(1:24),1),4))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + sed, 61 × 2 = 122

```bash
sed<<.�"s$?.$?&&0g"|tr�{A-Z,AG\ d-z}
BOoDCmORniNg,CBREen orb!
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3bYtTU2xs9DiVilXs9VTs1dQM0pVqSoo4qx11o3Qc3WMUUnSrarmc_PNdnHP9g_Iy_dJ1nJ2CXFPzFPKLkhQhhkDNgpkJAA)

`�` represents tabs.

Getting a good score without sed seems pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 32 bytes×4 `o`s=128 points

```
&p♭⍉↯4"Good morning, Green orb!"
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__JnDima3ijYnihq80Ikdvb2QgbW9ybmluZywgR3JlZW4gb3JiISIK)

On stdout:

```
GGGGoooooooodddd    mmmmoooorrrrnnnniiiinnnngggg,,,,    GGGGrrrreeeeeeeennnn    oooorrrrbbbb!!!!
```