# Draw a times table (also called modular multiplication circle) of a number \$n\$ with \$k\$ vertices

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output, geometry

Not to be confused with [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/103403/print-the-f-%C3%97-f-times-table).

You need to draw a times table (also known as [Cremona's method for cardioid generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid#Cardioid_as_envelope_of_a_pencil_of_lines)) as shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/qhbuKbxJsk8?t=42s). The number \$n\$ and \$k\$ will be the inputs.

**In the video n and k are 2 and 10 respectively.**

---

#### How to draw?

1. Draw a circle, divide its perimeter into equal spaced parts with
   \$k\$ points and number them with \$0, 1, 2, \dots, k-1\$ .
2. Draw \$k\$ line segments between \$i\$ and \$i\times n \mod k\$   for all integers \$i\$, \$0 \le i < k\$.

---

You can use any graphing library that your language allows.

Remember this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so keep the answer short and sweet.

---

#### Examples

```
Input : n = 2 and k = 27
```

[image]

```
Input : n = 5 and k = 10
```

[image]

You can also play around with it [here](http://www.hippiefuturist.me/4-d/times-table-geometry-simulator/). The modulus/points is \$k\$ while multiplication factor is \$n\$.

---

#### Challenge

You need to draw at least the circle and the lines.

You can output any file format (svg, png, jpeg) and HTML rendering is also allowed.

You can also write the image to STDOUT

---

Best of luck because you are going to need it!

Comment: From the looks of it, this seems to be [Cremona's method for cardioid generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid#Cardioid_as_envelope_of_a_pencil_of_lines). [Related Mathematica SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/177065/35945).

Comment: Your description seems to confuse `K` with `N` sometimes. I had to read it a couple times to see what you meant.

Comment: What do we need to draw, specifically? Just the lines? Circle and the points too?

Comment: Frankly, this question should have been posted [on the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/60043) and left there for some time (at least a few days). However, since this challenge is already posted, I advise that you keep it here, but make as many clarifications as possible before someone answers the question (to prevent invalidating answers).

Comment: I like this challenge, and I don't want it to end up being closed. I therefore suggest clarifying what exactly *has* to be included in the output: the circle, the points and the lines, the lines and the points, the lines only, etc.

Comment: I've been away for a bit, but when did PPCG get \$\LaTeX\$ again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Python 2 with pylab, <s>133</s> 129 bytes

```python
from pylab import*
n,k=input()
gca().add_patch(Circle((0,0),1))
a=2*pi/n
for i in range(n):c=i*a,k*i*a;plot(cos(c),sin(c))
show()
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

Comment: `for i in range(n):c=i*a,k*i*a;plot(cos(c),sin(c))` saves 4 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>280</s> <s>241</s> <s>235</s> 233 bytes

```python
from math import*
n,k=input()
a=2*pi/k
s='<svg viewBox="-49 -49 98 98"><circle r="49"/><path d="'
p=0;exec"s+='M%f,%f L%f,%f '%(49*cos(p),49*sin(p),49*cos(p*n),49*sin(p*n));p+=a;"*k
open('c.svg','w').write(s+'" stroke="red"/></svg>')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RaoQwFETf8xUhINfE7FpEaEWvD31uP0KysRusSUiy6/brbWwLhTvcwzAM47/S1dlm3@fgVrpO6UrN6l1Igli5oLH@lkpOJmyEN/VCIsIQ7x/0bvT26h7ITm1HD3Uv@dg4KBPUp6YBWduxehz8UXlBBsTjU68fWrFYIbwXsyxm@vb7oCjbTigXS89lpmjsH/14wv67mXnvK5x6JhbivLYlqHOeBBI24OctmKTLWAGjMQW3aGRBX44ldQ6NwPe9kc3zNw)

Saved 35 bytes due to removing `xmlns` attribute at the encouragement of [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17360/qwr); and 4 more since `%k` was not required. 4 more by using `exec` instead of `for i in range(k)`.

Writes an SVG file named `c.svg`. Look, ma! No graphics library! :)

Comment: works for me without `xmlns` tag. Is it optional?

Comment: @qwr: I think it's required in the relevant RFC if it is served as image/svg+xml (e.g., in a browser as a standalone file and not embedded in an html document). Otherwise - yes, It seems like, e.g., Photoshop will display it properly without. Would save 35 bytes; but seems a bit cheaty :).

Comment: well this is code golf so I say if it opens in a common program (opens in GNOME image viewer for me) then it's valid.

Comment: @qwr: Yes, it *is* code golf, so...

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>207</s> 206 bytes

```js
with(Math)f=(k,n,g=i=>[cos(i*=PI*2/k),sin(i)])=>`<svg viewBox=-1,-1,2.01,2.01><circle r=1 fill=none${s=` stroke=#000 stroke-width=.01 `}/><path d=M${[...Array(k)].map((_,i)=>g(i)+`L`+g(i*n)).join`M`}${s}/>`
;o.innerHTML=f(27,2)
```

```html
<div oninput=o.innerHTML=f(+k.value,+n.value)><input type=number min=2 value=27 id=k><input type=number min=2 value=2 id=n><div id=o>
```

Output of the function is an HTML5-compatible SVG snippet. The function itself is the first line of the snippet, the rest of the snippet merely serves to demonstrate the function. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: @ChasBrown Whoops, overlooked that, sorry. There goes 40 bytes...

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 160 bytes

```r
function(n,k,C=cospi,S=sinpi){par(pty="s")
plot(S(z<-0:2e4/1e4),C(z),'l',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',an=F,ax=F,xla="",yla="")
a=2/k*1:k
segments(C(a),S(a),C(a*n),S(a*n))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY69DoIwFEZ3nuIGB1pzxZ8wETuRmDg54AtUrFrB28ZeDGh8dkQTl3PO8A3ffTip4dRSxdaRIKyxUJUL3mKpgiVv5cvru/DcqzjEMvKNY1GK53q2yFcmmy9NJrEQT4lJk2CnO1YJJdj/Q5PaoO5GdI1WcYz9TzLSajWvp8u8joI53wxxEIXQEssvxprSr0fJ9zABy3B0JgA5hu8HcAT77S5NUzi0DNc2MLCDi34Y4IuBQ8/junItMeRy@AA)

[... or play with it if you want (change the code and press execute)](http://tpcg.io/aOhB0Z)

- -2 bytes thanks to @JayCE

Here's the appearance :

[image]

Comment: Nice! you can check with OP if it's acceptable to print axes, etc. to [save about 30 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY4xT8MwEEZ3/4pTUSU7MqFmrHoDCxILXbpVHZzgtm6Sc9S7NESI3x6MQIjtfU9v@K7zEefjQLXERJpsYz56f9W9TLjghVF9m0S/PllPhM/2vY0d1vreWWfs9G8YxVNXpZb1yq6sszHHHndZo1s3akRNBZvlMuN@3LgDNsojF49FHx8axeHUBRLWdWLt93wwliP90o8b/1wm8znfQRR4S4GBksD3S0gEu5dtWZZQDQKXgQUkwdnfAsg5QDVJrus0kMDazF8). also `a=T` works within `symbols` I believe. Probably more golfing possible...

Comment: @JayCe: saved several bytes still without showing the axes. I had to get rid of symbols since it's not really a perfect circle of radius 1 around zero. I resorted to plot

Comment: I can not test this right now but [it should save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY6xbsJAEET7@4qNI@Q7dDEBUVlsZSlSqhROhygOcwTHZs9i17FNlG93TESaefOkKeYyHnE8tlRIGUiTrcx34y66kQEjjoxq6iA619fN03O68uvF0q@NzfTV2LiObe96wZhiO/wXR/hiXT9FXzuMIjv8wSjGZVqpDjXN2cxmU90@dDuslEOerxaVYv9x9iSsM@22vDM2v/Pm3d0nmh@VYRG4KVWOXFJTjo9QChyCZ6AgcLsMgeD99S1JEti3Ap8tC0iAk/vyICcP@0GmdRFaEkjN@As)

Comment: Carefully rethinking the formula (...stupid of me) saved a lot of bytes :)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript 146 bytes + HTML 113 + Js Library [cardioidjs](https://mircot.github.io/blog/programming/javascript/2015/10/16/cardioidjs.html)  = 259 bytes

Note: I dont think this is allowed but acording to OP

> You can use any graphing library that your language allows.

Program ask for `k` and `n` and uses the lib to create the table

```js
_=document.getElementById('a');l=prompt;c=new Cardioid(_,{iterations:1000,pieces: (t=l("k"))%2?t-1:+t,fun1:l("n"),initialRotation: 180});c.draw()
```

```html
<script src="https://mircot.github.io/js/cardioid.js"></script>
<canvas id="a" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Looks valid. But boring. And some redundant spaces?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 + [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html), <s>126</s> 118 bytes

Just learn about [`clone`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html#turtle.clone). This version creates a turtle for each line drawn, so it clutters the screen a bit. Calling [`ht()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ht) will help.

```python
from turtle import*
n,k=eval(input())
a=clone()
exec('a.circle(99,360*n/k);circle(99,360/k);clone().goto(a.pos());'*k)
```

A direct port of my LOGO solution. However Python multi-turtle support is a bit different (they're named, not numbered), so turtle 0 in LOGO solution is the default turtle, and turtle 1 is `a`.

`[*map(goto,[a.pos(),pos()])]` is exactly 1 byte shorter than 
`p=pos();goto(a.pos());goto(p)`, and obviously much less readable...

---

This exits immediately after the drawing is done. To prevent that, adds `done()` at the end.

Because the drawing may be too slow, add `speed(0)` at the beginning (after the `import` statement)

I don't have Python 2 installed, but [this](https://tio.run/##TctBCoMwEEDRfU7hziRILAqCSA4TwlhDxpmQjtCePhW66e6/xS8fOZim1vbKZydXFYQunYWrWEVD9onKJdqo4CMywV3o5@XhxqzgDbEPLqYaEfS6DmjJbH@88Xvck4V1cIVf2pitt7m1Lw) (111 bytes) should work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 58 bytes

```
r=1
p=[0,...,k-1]2\pi/k
s=-cot(p/2+mod(np,k)/2)
sx+sinp-scosp
```

[View it on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bgtqwbwnsy), includes other functions for better visualization

Had more golfability than most Desmos answers, fun to work on. Note: since the link in the submission is broken, you can use this as an interactive tool to play around with them now!

Explanation:

```
r=1                       Draw circle
p=[0,...,k-1]2\pi/k       Generate list of angles (note: switching to degrees sould save a byte here, but we can't do that as it's not possible through code alone)
s=-cot(p/2+mod(np,k)/2)   Calculate slope of the line for each angle pair
sx+sinp-scosp             Draw the lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [FMSLogo](http://fmslogo.sourceforge.net/), <s>80</s> 77 bytes

```
[repeat ?[arc2 360/? 99 foreach list ask 1[arc2 360/?*?2 99 pos]pos "setpos]]
```

#### Usage

This is an [explicit-slot template](http://fmslogo.sourceforge.net/manual/explict-slot-templates.html), which can be used by typing, for example

```
apply [...] [54 2]
```

into the Logo prompt, replacing `[...]` with the program above.

It can be used to draw the circle anywhere on the screen, but the radius is hardcoded (99).

To clear the screen use [`cs`](http://fmslogo.sourceforge.net/manual/command-clearscreen.html).

#### Images

(FMSLogo also has a convenient command [`bitcopy`](http://fmslogo.sourceforge.net/manual/command-bitcopy.html) for copying to clipboard. Example run:

```
pu bk 100 bitcopy 200 200 home pd
```

)

[image: k = 54, n = 2]     [image: k = 90, n = 6]

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 167 bytes

An immediate window function that takes input and output onto the `Sheet1` object.

```vb
Set s=Sheet1.Shapes:s.AddShape(9,0,0,1E2,1E2).ShapeStyle=7:f=50:c=[2*Pi()/B1]:For i=0To[B1]:j=i*[A1]:s.AddLine f+f*Cos(c*i),f+f*Sin(c*i),f+f*Cos(c*j),f+f*Sin(c*j):Next
```

#### Ungolfed and Commented

```vb
Set s=Sheet1.Shapes                                             ''  On the Sheet1 Object
s.AddShape(9,0,0,1E2,1E2).ShapeStyle=7                          ''  Add a blue circle
f=50                                                            ''  Hold var as 50
c=[2*Pi()/B1]                                                   ''  Calc Rads Splitting circle into k slices
For i=0To[B1]                                                   ''  Iterate from 0 to k
j=i*[A1]                                                        ''  Calculate Next Point
s.AddLine f+f*Cos(c*i),f+f*Sin(c*i),f+f*Cos(c*j),f+f*Sin(c*j)   ''  Draw a line from i to i*n Mod k
Next                                                            ''  Loop
```

#### Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

## [Small Basic](http://www.smallbasic.com), 218 bytes

A Script that takes input from the `TextWindow` and outputs to the `GraphicsWindow` Object

```vb
n=TextWindow.Read()
k=TextWindow.Read()
GraphicsWindow.DrawEllipse(0,0,100,100)
f=50
c=2*Math.Pi/k
For i=0To k
GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(f+f*Math.Cos(c*i),f+f*Math.Sin(c*i),f+f*Math.Cos(c*i*n),f+f*Math.Sin(c*i*n))
EndFor
```

[Try it at SmallBasic.com!](http://www.smallbasic.com/program?KTW208) *Requires IE/Silverlight*

#### Output

Input `3`,`24`

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (love2d Framework),281 bytes

```
j,p,z,w,v=love,math,100,200,90 g,r=j.graphics,p.rad c=g.circle function j.load(b)n,k=b[1],b[2]m= 360/k::t::a=function(i)return z*p.sin(r(m*i +v))+w,z*p.cos(r(m*i+v))+w end c("line",w,w,z)for i=1,k do x,y=a(i)c("fill",x,y,3)l=(i*n)%k d,e=a(l)g.line(x,y,d,e)end g.present()goto t end
```

If this is copied in a main.lua file and run it will show it on screen

output for n=2,k=22

[image]

also beware if you run it, that it will probably tell you that it is frozen because it is in an endless draw function in the load function
but it will show it on the screen.

Also here is a clean version

```
--definitions of everything
j,p,z,w,v=love,math,100,200,90 
g,r=j.graphics,p.rad c=g.circle 
function j.load(b)
  --get the parameters
  n,k=b[1],b[2]
  m= 360/k
  --goto label
  ::t::
  --function which takes a point number as input and outputs the x,y adds also 90 to it because why ever love starts 
   a=function(i)return z*p.sin(r(m*i +v))+w,z*p.cos(r(m*i+v))+w end
   --draw the circle
   c("line",w,w,z)
   for i=1,k do 
     --get point position and draw it
     x,y=a(i)
     c("fill",x,y,3)
     --calculate and print the line to the other point
     l=(i*n)%k
     d,e=a(l)
     g.line(x,y,d,e)
   end 
   --show it on screen
   g.present()
   goto t 
end
```

If someone also wants to play around with it here a version which you can
change the n with up and down and the k with left and right arrows :)

```
--definitions of everything
j,p,z,w,v=love,math,100,200,90 
g,r=j.graphics,p.rad c=g.circle 
function j.load(b)
  --get the parameters
  n,k=b[1],b[2]

end


function u(n,k)
--function which takes a point number as input and outputs the x,y adds also 90 to it because why ever love starts 
   a=function(i)return z*p.sin(r(m*i +v))+w,z*p.cos(r(m*i+v))+w end
   --draw the circle
   m= 360/k

   c("line",w,w,z)
   for i=1,k do 
     --get point position and draw it
     x,y=a(i)
     c("fill",x,y,3)
     --calculate and print the line to the other point
     l=(i*n)%k
     d,e=a(l)
     g.line(x,y,d,e)
   end 
end

function j.draw()
  --n=n+0.001
  --k=k+0.01
  u(n,k)
  love.graphics.print("n: "..n.."\nk: "..k,0,0)
end

function j.keypressed(ke,s)
  k=k*1
  if ke== "up"then
    n=n+1
  elseif ke=="down" then
    if n >1 then n=n-1 end
  elseif ke=="right" then
    k=k+1
  elseif ke=="left" then
    if k>1 then 
      k=k-1 
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 57 bytes

*<sup><sup>No MATL answer here yet! yay!</sup></sup>*

```apl
{n←⍺⋄P5.G.circle 3⍴30⋄{P5.G.ln↑30×1+2 1○ᑈ1n×⍵×○2÷k}¨⍳k←⍵}
```

Made with help from dzaima.

Draws a 30x30 circle  with the times table for `n` and `k`.

Function submission which takes arguments as `n f k`, and will display properly on a default sized canvas.

This uses the formula from [user58543's answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168542/80214)

You can test this out using [this file](https://github.com/razetime/code-golf/blob/master/APL-code/circlenet.apl) and dzaima's APLP5 engine.

### Explanation:

```apl
{n←⍺⋄P5.G.circle 3⍴30⋄{P5.G.ln↑30×1+2 1○ᑈ1n×⍵×○2÷k}¨⍳k←⍵}
{n←⍺⋄                                                   k←⍵} store left arg in n and right arg in k
      P5.G.circle 3⍴30⋄                                      Draw circle of radius 30

                                                        ⍳k   generate range 1..k
                       {                              }¨     Execute the following for each number i:
                                            1n×⍵×○2÷k        Multiply [1,n] with i×2π/k
                                      2 1○ᑈ                  Take cos and sin of each of those
                                30×1+                        Multiply 30, add 30 to them
                              ↑                              Convert to matrix
                        P5.G.ln                              Plot a line using those coordinates
```

#### Output for `n=5, k=10`:

[image]

Comment: [`:-)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214457/36398)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>39</s> <s>37</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
:qG/ti*vO9Wt:w/h,18L*ZeXG1IZG
```

Inputs are `k`, then `n`.

Try at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=%3AqG%2Fti%2avO9Wt%3Aw%2Fh%2C18L%2aZeXG1IZG&inputs=101%0A17&version=22.3.0)!

### How it works

```
:         % Implicit input: k. Range: [1 2 ... k]
q         % Subtract 1, element-wise: [0 1 ... k-1]
G/        % Push k again; divide element-wise: [0 1/k ...(k-1)/k]
t         % Duplicate
i*        % Input: n. Multiply element-wise: gives [0 n/k ... n*(k-1)/k]
v         % Concatenate vertically: gives 2-row matrix [0 1   ... k-1;
          %                                             0 n/k ... n*(k-1)/k]
O         % Push 0
9W        % Push 9; exponential with base 2: gives 512
t         % Duplicate
:         % Range: gives [1 2 ... 512]
w         % Swap: moves copy of 512 to top
/         % Divide, element-wise: gives [1/512 2/512 ... 1]
h         % Concatenate: gives [0 1/512 2/512 ... 1]
,         % Do the following twice
  18L     %   Push 2*pi*j (predefined literal)
  *       %   Multiply, element-wise
  Ze      %   Exponential with base e, element-wise. Each imaginary number
          %   becomes a point in the unit circle
  XG      %   Plot. Since the input is complex, this plots in the complex
          %   plane. The first time this plots the 2-row matrix defining the
          %   lines, with each column of the matrix plotted separately. The
          %   second time it plots the 512-vector with points in the circle
  1IZG    %   Hold on. This causes the next plot to be added, instead of 
          %   overwriting the previous one
```

Comment: There we go. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Small Basic](http://www.smallbasic.com) + Turtle, 390 bytes

A Script that takes input from the `TextWindow` and outputs to the `GraphicsWindow` Object

```vb
n=TextWindow.Read()
k=TextWindow.Read()
For i=0To 360
Turtle.Angle=i
Turtle.Move(2.618) 
EndFor
r=150
c=2*Math.Pi/k  
For i=0To k
Turtle.PenUp()
Turtle.MoveTo(470+r*Math.Cos(c*i),240+r*Math.Sin(c*i))
Turtle.PenDown()
Turtle.MoveTo(470+r*Math.Cos(c*i*n),240+r*Math.Sin(c*i*n))
EndFor
GraphicsWindow.DrawLine(f+f*Math.Cos(c*i),f+f*Math.Sin(c*i),f+f*Math.Cos(c*i*n),f+f*Math.Sin(c*i*n))
EndFor
```

[Try it at SmallBasic.com!](http://www.smallbasic.com/program?PQZ111) *Requires IE/Silverlight*

#### Ungolfed and Commented

```vb
n=TextWindow.Read()                                         ''  Take Input, n
k=TextWindow.Read()                                         ''  Take Input, k
For i=0To 360                                               ''  Draw a Circle of Radius 150
  Turtle.Angle=i                                            ''  By turning 1 degree
  Turtle.Move(2.618)                                        ''  And moving Pi*300/360 Units
EndFor                                                      ''  360 times
r=150                                                       ''  Hold Radius variable
c=2*Math.Pi/k                                               ''  Hold Rad Constant
For i=0To k                                                 ''  Iterate over i
  Turtle.PenUp()                                            ''  Stop Drawing
  Turtle.MoveTo(470+r*Math.Cos(c*i),240+r*Math.Sin(c*i))    ''  Move to Position i
  Turtle.PenDown()                                          ''  Start Drawing again
  Turtle.MoveTo(470+r*Math.Cos(c*i*n),240+r*Math.Sin(c*i*n))''  Move to Position (i*n)Mod k
EndFor                                                      ''  Loop
```

#### Output

Input `3`,`72`

[image: Pic]